# Sign in failure for android Photohunt

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I've been running the PhotoHunt example (https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/android‎
) from Google and I can't figure out what/where I went wrong. I've followed the tutorial and I have the created the app in the app engine, I've got the server running locally, but when I run the client application on my android device and I try to login into Google plus I get the following error in my debugger.

```
... failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 8888): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

It appears to me that client can't reach the server. I've opened up port 8888 on my computer running the server, turned off my firewall, and had the port forwarded by router. I'm not exactly sure where I've messed up.

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the tutorial I realized that some of the features only became available when you deployed to the google app engine. Once I deployed to the app engine I was able to get everything working. Just as a note compiling/deploying the javascript files (js) had some issues. You need to download and point your jre path to a jdk source. I also needed to add the jdk to eclipse ini file (-vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x\bin\javaw.exe" where x is the version of the jdk that you have).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to connect to your local development web server after doing the following:

Right-click your project name -> Run As -> Run Configurations... -> Arguments

In the Program arguments field, change

```
--port=8888
```

to

```
--port=8888 --address=0.0.0.0
```

Then stop and restart your application.

Comment: I tried both of those techniques and neither fixed my problem. Good suggestion though. My guess is that some port configuration was wrong (router vs pc).